# What is the api for getting number of followers and followings in Flickr?

Tags: android, flickr

I am integrating a Flickr app and I want to get the complete user information.

I am using `flickr.people.getInfo` method for that but there I am not getting the followers and following list of a particular user.

Can any one suggest a method for that?

Comment: refer this link you will get API. https://www.flickr.com/services/api/

Comment: thanks, but i have already done that and i am not able to find anything that returns the followers/following list or count

Comment: @Archana I have the same question too. Can you help?